# Create Clickable Tooltip For Silverlight Controls

Tags: xaml, silverlight, tooltip, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I add a button inside Tool Tip and handle the button click event. 
and in run time I move the cursor to do click, the tool tip disappears.
my question is:
how can I do the tool tip don't disappear, so I can click the button inside it?

Comment: What you describe is (conceptually) not a tooltip anymore. It's a context menu. And I can't recommend using the Silverlight TooltipService for creating context menus. How about opening a popup on RightMouseButtonDown?

Comment: I don't want create Context Menu. I have a Chart and Print Button inside Tool Tip.